# Cold water pipe frozen, hot water fine

Tags: plumbing, water, freezing, plumbing-fixture

Our cold water in the kitchen isn't working, the hot water is fine. It is a single faucet, so when I turn it to cold water, nothing comes out. I turned the heat up in the house, and have opened the cabinet doors. I saw on another site, to let the hot water run for 10-20 minutes, and hope the close proximity of the pipes help the cold. Any other tips?

Comment: Be prepared ... when it thaws, you may find that the pipe has split. I would turn off the water to that run if you have to leave it unattended.

Comment: Thanks. We have cold and hot water to every other faucet, just not this one.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the frozen pipe or the cavity in the wall/floor where it is you can use a hair dryer to heat the air around the pipe (a cheap hair dryer blowing up into a wall from a basement unfroze a pipe within minutes for me).  I would not apply high heat (e.g. heat gun) to the pipe directly as you can cause the water to expand and damage it.  If you have direct access to where the pipe is frozen, applying a towel soaked in hot water is another option.

If you own the home, look into insulating the pipes and the cavity they are in.  If you rent, inform the owner of the problem.

Comment: Thanks. We can't see the pipe, so we have a heater on in the general area of the pipes leading to the basement.